# Python entering labels into notebook section

Tags: python, tkinter

Using this code I cannot figure out how to enter the label into the notebook page(second last line).

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
window = Tk()
window.title("test")

nb = ttk.Notebook(window)
nb.pack()

SortingPage = tkinter.Frame(nb)
SearchingPage = tkinter.Frame(nb)
nb.add(SortingPage, text="Sorting")
nb.add(SearchingPage, text="Searching")
nb.select(SortingPage)
nb.enable_traversal()

SortingPage.text1 = Label(SortingPage, text="sample text")

window.mainloop()
```

How could this be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of placement managers. Example: add `SortingPage.text1.pack()` before `window.mainloop()`. Hope that's helpful!